# How to update row in one table based on value from another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Lets say that I have a table called `users` that stores `id` and `points` and another table called `unlimted_points` that stores `id`, `order_date` and `old_points`.

How do transfer a value from `old_points` to `points` where the id is identical and the `ordere_date` being `>= (NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY)`?

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server it would be as follows: 
update table1 
   set table1.Price = table2.price 
   FROM table1  INNER JOIN  table2 on table1.id = table2.id

I think MY SQL is as follows:

UPDATE tableToUpdate
INNER JOIN original USING (value)
SET tableToUpdate.id = original.id

I hope this helps.